# MySQL Server overloaded with PDO request -- How to prevent?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I got a PHP script which browses files containing infos about 1M or 2M users
Some users need to be updated due to changes provided.

I must be very naive, but thought my sequential code would send request after request, and couldn't overload the servers.
The fact is : I put the 4 cpus of a production server to 95% use at my first run, and had a cron crash tonight, on another server.

So I guess PDO requests are sent to the server, and asynchronously executed.  Nice, but... how can I avoid to overload it then ?
I couldn't find anything on the topic, so I guess I'm not looking for the right keywords.

My code logic is pretty simple :

For every user, I send first a SELECT request to check if the UPDATE is necessary, and if it is, I actually execute the UPDATE request.

*I wonder why, but checking with the first SELECT request proved more efficient than just "updating 0 lines" with the same WHERE restrictions*

The code can be roughly summed-up as this :

```
foreach ($parsed_user as $user => $infos) {
    //PDO value bindings
    if ($stmt_check_user_need_update->execute()){
        continue;

    if ($stmt_update->execute()) {
        //log success
    }
    else {
        //log error
}
```

As long as it doesn't crash, this works pretty well.
The thing is... I'd like it to be reliable, and avoid impacting production environments.

I run updates on both SQL-Server and MySQL.

Comment: You're describing an SQL problem, but showing no SQL ...

Comment: your keyword is "QUEUE", or "RabbitMQ"

Comment: @Unamata Sanatarai This looks relevant, for sure.
But I feel I'm in need of base knowldge of how the process works, first.

While queues are probably the solution for heavy workloads, I'm really running basic scripts, and am not sure it's the right approach here.
I would have expected a simple way to check for the current "DB usage", "running requests", or something like this.

Comment: I just tried to run my script locally, and MySQL's "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;" tells me I never have 2 requests at once.  
While the behaviour might be different on another server, I'm skeptical about the possible causes.  
Could my 95%-4-proc usage be because I was using an SQL-Server DB, and the driver behaves differently ?

Comment: Obviously, your assumption is wrong. Most likely your problem is caused by non-noptimal database architecture, lack of indexes or something like that. Taking actions out of false guesswork is the worst course you could take.